# Rails/ActiveRecord: not retrieving the correct column through a join with a has_one/ belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

**Models**

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency_feature
  ...
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :agency_features, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class AgencyFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  has_one :feature
end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "agency_features", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "agency_id"
  t.integer "feature_id"
  t.boolean "enabled"
end

add_index "agency_features", ["agency_id"], name: "index_agency_features_on_agency_id", using: :btree
add_index "agency_features", ["feature_id"], name: "index_agency_features_on_feature_id", using: :btree
```

**The problem**

`Agency.first.agency_feature` gives me:

```
<AgencyFeature id: 508, agency_id: 1, feature_id: 1, enabled: false>
```

and `Agency.first.agency_features.first.agency`returns the correct agency.

The problem is `Agency.first.agency_features.first.feature` gives a *column doesn't exist* error and is trying to look for `"agency_feature_id"` inside of features.

How do I make it look for the feature with an id that corresponds to the "feature_id" attribute inside of AgencyFeature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try running the migration again. I agree with Marnuss here. I think you don't have the field agency_feature_id in your Feature table. It should look something like -

```
create_table "features", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "agency_feature_id"
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `has_one :feature`, with `belongs_to :feature`

```
class AgencyFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

Comment: I would like to do this with the current relationship, which should be a has_one, like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. With `has_one :feature`, you'd need to have column `agency_feature_id` in table `features`. I don't think thats what you need. Seems to me, that you have a generic join table, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this one out by changing key attributes in the feature model.

```
class AgencyFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  has_one :feature, foreign_key: "id", primary_key: "feature_id"
end
```

Now I can use the has_one relationship like I intended. Where feature_id corresponds to the id of the feature in the feature table.